# How to debug my poker game recursion logic?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static ArrayList<Hand> getPossibleHands(Hand h) {
    ArrayList<Hand> allPossible = new ArrayList<Hand>();
    addNext(allPossible, h);
    return allPossible;
}

public static void addNext(ArrayList<Hand> poss, Hand h) {
    if (h.cards.size() == 5)
        poss.add(h);
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            Card c = Card.makeCard(i);
            if (!h.contains(c))
                h.add(c);
            addNext(poss,h);
        }
}
```

The code above is supposed to essentially take an incomplete poker board (anywhere from 0-4 cards) and return all possible complete boards (5 cards). The logic that I feel like it should follow is as follows: recurse through every combination of adding valid (not on the board already) cards until the size of the board is equal to 5 in which case it will add the board to the list and skip over the rest of the function.

However upon using a print statement at the beginning of the function I see that hand sizes of greater than 5 or being created. Since the first part of the function should catch all hands at 5 and terminate it there, I don't see how the code executes at the rest of the function.

Comment: Does the order of the cards matter?  That is, are 2 hands considered distinct if they only differ in the order of the cards?

Comment: @Scott Hunter no, order doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Your class should receive stack overflow with an empty hand.
You send new Card(0) to the hand. This is added.
Then you call add next again - and the 'for' starts from 0 again. Checks adds 1. Then starts from 0 - it is there, does not add anything and starts over. Where it starts from 0. Does not do anything. Starts from 0. Ad infinum -> StackOverFlow.

You also need to reset to previous state of the  hand every time you finish with 5 cards and backtrack.

If you want a recursive solution you can try :

```
private static ArrayList<Hand> getPossibleHands(Hand h) {
        ArrayList<Integer> except;
        if (h.cards == null) except = new ArrayList<>();
        else
            except = h.cards.stream().map(c -> (c.getCard())).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        ArrayList<Hand> allPossible = new ArrayList<>();
        addNext(allPossible, h, except);
        return allPossible;
    }

    private static void addNext(ArrayList<Hand> poss, Hand h, ArrayList<Integer> except) {
        //assuming hands 0-4 - we don't need to check on entry, only when we add
        Hand localHand = h.copy();
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            if (except.contains(i)) continue;
            Card c = Card.makeCard(i);
            if (!localHand.contains(c)) {
                addNext(poss, localHand.copy(), copyExcept(except, i));
                localHand.add(c);
                if (localHand.cards.size() == 5) {
                    poss.add(localHand);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

    }

    private static ArrayList<Integer> copyExcept(ArrayList<Integer> except, int i) {
        ArrayList<Integer> clonedExcept = new ArrayList<>(except);
        clonedExcept.add(i);
        return clonedExcept;
    }


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Hand {
    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean contains(Card c) {
        for (Card card : cards) {
            if (card.getCard() == c.getCard())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void add(Card c) {
        cards.add(c);
    }

    Hand copy() {
        Hand temp = new Hand();
        for (Card c : cards) {
            temp.add(new Card(c.getCard()));
        }
        return temp;
    }
}


class Card {
    private int card;

    public Card(int card) {
        this.card = card;
    }

    public static Card makeCard(int i) {
        return new Card(i);
    }

    public int getCard() {
        return card;
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems more complicated than it needs to be...  i'll give a shot but i want to use my own classes and methods. I have a duplicate, contains, and add method. I'm not sure what getCard() is in your solution.

Comment: Edited it add the card class. It is sure more complicated than it should be :) ill see if i can come with shorter version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, `h` is (presumably) empty.  So `addNext` will loop through all possible cards, and since none of them are in the hand, add each card to the hand, regardless of how many cards are currently in the hand.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your for loop is eventually adding whole deck to hand.

Answer (score -1):

In your loop you run 52 iterations. On each iteration you (conditionally) add a card to the hand and then you call your function recursively. But after that recursive call has returned, you go to the next iteration and again add a card to the hand.

So that '5 card restriction' does not restrict anything here.